# codeigniter admin route is not working. it returns "The requested URL was not found on this server. "

Tags: codeigniter

i need to access the admin controller in codeigniter using the url mywebsite.com/admin

but it returns "The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again" error

my code is

routes.php

```
$route['admin'] = 'admin/adminmain';
```

adminmain.php  (admincontroller)

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Adminmain extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {

        $this->load->view('admin/adminhome');
    }   
}
```

Comment: Is your adminmain.php file in a folder called "admin"?

Comment: yes, I create a folder admin and put the main controller for admin is adminmain.php

Comment: is the controller file really adminmain.php? It should be (look carefully) Adminmain.php

Comment: Is your base_url set properly in config file and also .htaccess is configured?

Answer (score 0):

In Codeigniter 3 or above controllers name should be capitalized.

Answer (score 0):

The controller file name should be Adminmain.php

Answer (score 0):

controller file name should be Adminmain.php and try to define route like: $route['admin'] = 'admin/Adminmain'; and also check r u defining admin folder under controller folder